# Unable to increase the scroll view width of horizontal UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

In my application, I rotated the table view for 90 degrees i.e., the table view is now horizontal table view. After rotation I tried to increase its scroll size as I was unable to view the last row but I couldn't increase it. As table view is sub class of UIScroll view, I tried to change it in Interface Builder but nothing solved my problem. Please tell me how to increase this table view scroll view width to view all the contents.

```
rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
tableView.transform = rotateTable;
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 333, self.view.frame.size.width , 37)];
```

In IB,Size Inspector: Scroll View Size: Scroller Insets : Right : 500 (I changed the Right attribute to increase the width)

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manage it. Tableview does it itself. Your problem is frame of tableview. Your tableview is crossing bounds of it's superview(view in which tableview is added). Check tableview's frame. Make sure it will not exceed bounds of superview.

Comment: Table View didn't exceed the bounds of its super view, still not able to see the last row